# yii cactiveform model property not shown in textfield

Tags: php, yii, active-form

I have this form field in a CActive form:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <?= $form->labelEx($model,'naam'); ?>
    <?= $form->textField($model,'naam',array('size'=>40,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
    <?= $form->error($model,'naam'); ?>
</div>
```

When I want to edit this property it is not shown in my textfield, but when I use `var_dump` to check if the property is set, I get the expected value. What I did notice is that this only happens when the value contains a character like é. Is this a bug? Or does someone knows this problem and how to fix it?

Kind regards,

Pim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must configure first for supporting foreign characters

**1.You could add a meta tag to your HTML pages like**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

**2.Set default_charset to utf8 in your php.ini**

**3.Add the following PHP command to Yii's index.php:**

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');.
```

It works for me. I think it will be helpful. for more details

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/16/how-to-set-up-unicode/

Comment: yup I figured out it was the meta-tag which wasn't set the right way. Thanks anyway!